# HTML/CSS ; How do I make this navigation bar (aquablue one? On the left is a logo in .png format, how does it stick out of background?

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox, navbar

I should use flexbox method on this and I am a little confused on how to do the whole main body, with the background picture of a singer.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/X770d.png

Comment: Could you provide us with what you have already done and what has failed when you attempted to do it so that we can help you based on your context? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

to make that navigation bar you can either begin from scratch or use Bootstrap to speed up the process. In order to make a navigation bar similar to the one in the image you have provided you will need a combination of HTML and CSS. You can create a div container using `<div></div>` and give it a class such as `.navbar` and then using CSS you can assign the class a `background-color: aquablue;`. Give the class a `margin-top: 5%;` or so to replicate the image you have provided and then a margin from the left as well. From there you just have to create an unordered list `<ul></ul>` and add the navigation bar items using `<li></li>` tags and give those all your desired font and positioning using CSS. the opacity of the navigation bar in the image you provided is roughly 0.7 I would assume so the background is still visible. You can also visit the Bootstrap documentation at this link: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/ in order to use their navigation bars in your website with their custom CSS ready for you. As for the logo image, I would assume that it is part of the entire image present at the top of the webpage and the blue bar had been placed over it but I can't tell without checking to see if the entire logo is a hyperlink or not... Hopefully this helps!

(You would still need to assign width and height attributes to the navigation bar in CSS and much more but that is briefly how to do it)